# Is there any way of importing background terrains in paraview?

Tags: paraview, 3d-modelling

I just want to know if there's a way to include a background terrain in paraview, it could be roads, trees, clouds, landscapes etc. I checked the paraview user guide and tutorials for version 5.5 but couldn't find any such features. I also would appreciate any online resources which I can use for further help (terrains, tutorials, etc).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing specific, you can load a 2D background though, or you can just load your "background terrain" geometry has any other dataset.